# Read connection from appsettings.json in .net core 1.1 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, database-connection, .net-core

I am create a web api project in .net core 1.1 but problem is when its try to read connectionstring from appsettings.json an exception occurs .

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file
>   'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical
>   path is
>   'C:\Test\netCoreWebApi\netCoreWebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json'.'

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<NorthWindDBContext>();
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddScoped<ICategory_Product, Category_ProductRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

also eclare connectionstring in DBContext class (may be I am doing wrong here)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("northwindConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);


        }
```

so wats the correct way .

please help .

Comment: Does `appsettings.json` available on physical path? and which version you are using - VS2015 (project.json) or VS2017(csproj)?

Comment: File `appsettings.json` should be added to your application entry point and it should have `Build action: Content` property if used in a web project. If the problem hasn't beed resolved try to set `Copy to output directory: Always` property.

Comment: @Sanket VS2017(csproj).

Comment: As metioned by Ilya Chumakov, In appsetting.json properties, Set **Copy always** for Copy to Output Directory property.

Comment: Did this but ,not working

Comment: So, after building your project, do u see `appsettings.json` in physical path or not?

Comment: appsettings.json file in bin/debug but through an error
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: I think, after doing previous settings, appsettings.json related issue is resolved. Now, you are facing EFcore related error.